# Geometric Progression via 10% consecutive term

Tags: geometric-progressions

> Determine the sum of the geometric progression with each consecutive term being 10% larger than the previous term and the first term is 2400.

I tried solving it like this below via the Geometric progression formula. I know my $a_1$ is 2400. I think my common ratio is 1.10 since it's 10% bigger. I don't think I did the method correct and would like some help. 
$$
\frac{2400(1 - 0.1^{13})}{1 - 0.1}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common ratio is $1.1$ not $0.1$. You can write the formula as $$2400\frac{1.1^{13}-1}{1.1-1}= 58854.5$$